# Clear Store sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Hi i have an app that populates store using a proxy. I want to clear the store on click of a button and let the user enter in different information and repopulate if that makes sense. I am currently using :

```
 window.location.reload();
```

but this gives a white screen for a couple of seconds which is not nice. I have also tried the following :

```
var store = Ext.getStore('Places'); 

store.getProxy().clear();

store.data.clear(); store.sync();
```

but this gives an error relating to the .getProxy()

I have also tried:

```
Ext.StoreMgr.get('Places').removeAll();
Ext.StoreMgr.get('Places').sync();
```

but when the i go to repopulate the old data remains. Is there a way to clear the stores?

Comment: `var store = Ext.getStore('Places'); store.removeAll();`  isn't working ?

Comment: I think the problem might be with my selectfields not returning to their initial value. And when the user goes to search again the same parameters are been passed back.I have tried clearing them with the following but no success:                                  var visitEmpty = this.getVisit().setValue('food|restaurant|');
     var location =this.getLocation().setValue('currentlocation');
     var radiusEmpty = this.getRadius().setValue('1');

Answer (score 5):

The best Way to clear Store is

```
         var store = Ext.getStore('SessionStore');
         store.load();
         store.getProxy().clear();
         store.data.clear();
         store.sync();
```

Comment: Hi i have tried the above and i am getting error message Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'clear'

Comment: I think the problem might be with my selectfields not returning to their initial value. And when the user goes to search again the same parameters are been passed back.I have tried clearing them with the following but no success:                                  var visitEmpty = this.getVisit().setValue('food|restaurant|');
     var location =this.getLocation().setValue('currentlocation');
     var radiusEmpty = this.getRadius().setValue('1');